# Wget TLS SNI support setting server name

Tags: ssl, wget, sni

Does `wget` support [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)? If so, can someone show me a sample command? I am not able to find in the man page how to set the server name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing you need to configure to use SNI but you have to use a wget version which supports it. Support for SNI [was added in version 1.14](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7323) which was released 08/2012.