# Unable to verify ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, wget

I am not able to verify webmaster account of one of my client.

Google is saying "Verification failed - The connection to your server timed out."

When I tried to do wget the URL, I found below error. Can someone please help me resolving this?

```
[pdurgapal]$ wget https://atlanticdiscountstore.com
--2017-06-28 11:48:48--  https://atlanticdiscountstore.com
Resolving atlanticdiscountstore.com... 188.241.58.18
Connecting to atlanticdiscountstore.com|188.241.58.18|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify atlanticdiscountstore.com’s certificate, issued by “/CN=baldwincountyunited.com”:
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
ERROR: certificate common name “baldwincountyunited.com” doesn’t match requested host name “atlanticdiscountstore.com”.
To connect to atlanticdiscountstore.com insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.
[pdurgapal]$
```

Comment: The time-to-first-bye on that page is 42 seconds. The site takes way too long to load, which is probably why Google is timing out the connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wget TLS SNI support setting server name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559821/wget-tls-sni-support-setting-server-name)

Answer (score 1):

You must be using a very old version of wget which has no support for SNI. When using a proper client with support for SNI the certificate can be verified. Apart from that the server is terrible slow in responding after the TLS handshake is successfully done, but this is not the issue you asked about.

To demonstrate the problem an access to the site without SNI:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect atlanticdiscountstore.com:443  |\
  openssl x509 -text
...
Subject: CN=baldwincountyunited.com
...
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
  DNS:baldwincountyunited.com, DNS:mail.baldwincountyunited.com, DNS:www.baldwincountyunited.com
```

and with SNI:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect atlanticdiscountstore.com:443 \
  -servername atlanticdiscountstore.com |\
  openssl x509 -text
  ...
  Subject: ... CN=*.atlanticdiscountstore.com
  ...
  X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
     DNS:*.atlanticdiscountstore.com, DNS:atlanticdiscountstore.com
```